# INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY - why works for some queries

Tags: hive

This query works fine - stores result in a file:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/export/home/devtmpl' 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
select * from cincdr where eventdatetime > '2015-02-15' and sliceEventCostVat is not null;
```

But this one creates an empty file :

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/export/home/devtmpl' 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
select * from cincdr where sliceEventCostVat is not null;
```

As you can see, second query differs only in 'where' clause.

If I run queries without `INSERT OVERWRITE ...` both give non empty result...

Have you any idea why INSERT OVERWRITE gives different result than a simple query?

Regards
Pawel

Comment: Just to be a pedant,it also differs in the local directory you're using.

Comment: yeah, Thanks for watchfulness! :-) Queries have the same directories.